# In SQL Server Management Studio what is SQLCMD mode?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In SQL Server Management Studio I would like to know what is SQLCMD mode?

Comment: See [The SQLCMD workbench](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/the-sqlcmd-workbench/) for some examples where this is useful.

Comment: And dba.se: http://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=sqlcmd

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Exactly what it sounds like.

It is a mode that lets you author SQLCMD scripts.

From MSDN - [Editing SQLCMD Scripts with Query Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187.aspx):

> To use the Database Engine Query Editor to write or edit SQLCMD scripts, you must enable the SQLCMD scripting mode.

In SQL Server Management Studio, set this via the Query menu (Query -> SQLCMD Mode).

Comment: It obviously wasn't me, but a lot of resources aren't real forthcoming about the difference between using SQLCMD and just running some T-SQL statements inside of Management Studio.  A conversion script that Visual Studio generated for me last week does a check to see if SQLCMD is enabled and refuses to run if it's not, and there appears to be an option to enable/disable it in the Query menu for Management Studio.  So there's a difference, but a lot of resources basically just say that SQLCMD is this great, wonderful device that lets you run T-SQL statements and batches and leave it at that.

Comment: This answer explains SQLCMD by using SQLCMD and basically is not much more than a Link to MSDN. So it does not help.

Comment: And even that link to MSDN doesn't explain *at all* why someone might choose to use a SQLCMD script instead of just straight TSQL. It just explains the mechanics and syntax of editing.

Comment: Re. "And even that link to MSDN doesn't explain at all why someone might choose to use a SQLCMD script instead of just straight TSQL.": The 2nd sentence of the article linked (at least the current "03/14/2017" version if not also the version when linked) says "why" - "You use SQLCMD scripts when you have to process Windows System commands and Transact-SQL statements in the same script.".

Answer (score 91):

I did some more research, so here's my understanding of this to extend what has been written so far:

### What is SQLCMD

[SQLCMD.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms162773.aspx) is a console utility included in the instalation of SQL Server 2005 and higher. You can typically find it in a path like `c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE`.

It is a simple scripting environment that allows automation of tasks related to SQL server. For example, you can write and execute a script that will login to a specific instance of SQL Server, execute scripts from a given directory on this connection and store the output in a specified file.

[`Invoke-Sqlcmd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/cc281720%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) cmdlet was introduced with SQL Server 2008 as a mean to replace this tool with a standardized, Powershell-based approach, preserving most of the original syntax and functionality.

### What is SQLCMD mode in SSMS

In SSMS, *SQLCMD mode* is a script execution mode that simulates the sqlcmd.exe environment and therefore accepts some commands that are not part of T-SQL language.
Unlike `sqlcmd.exe`, it contacts the database using *SqlClient* (the same way as SSMS), not *ODBC* data provider, so in some aspects it might have different behaviour than `sqlcmd.exe`.

Executing scripts in SQLCMD mode allows to use commands typical to `sqlcmd.exe` environment. However, there's no IntelliSense or debugging support for SQLCMD mode, so maintaining scripts that mix clean T-SQL with SQLCMD-specific code can be a pain. Therefore, it should be used only when it's necessary.

### Example use case

Let's suppose that a company has a naming convention for databases that include environment in the name, eg: *MyDb_**Prod***, *MyDb_**Test***, *MyDb_**Dev***. This convention might be used to [minimize chance of mistakes](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic949029-373-1.aspx).

When a developer writes a T-SQL script, it will have to be executed in different environments in deployment/testing process, which would require many versions of the code:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM [MyDb_Dev].[dbo].[MyTable1] -- MyDb_Dev -> MyDb_Test -> MyDb_Prod
```

Instead, we can assume that database name will be provided as a SQLCMD variable in deployment process and have exactly the same file deployed to all environments:

```
 -- :setvar databaseName "MyDb_Dev" -- uncomment for testing in SSMS

 SELECT *
 FROM [$(databaseName)].[dbo].[MyTable1]
```

(in this simple example database name could be omitted altogether, but if you have cross-database joins, using database name is necessary)

Comment: Thanks, @buli. This answer is the only one that explains why someone who normally uses only TSQL in SSMS might instead choose to make and run a SQLCMD script.

Comment: A use case I am considering: For Availability Groups, you are of course working with multiple servers. It should be possible to write T-SQL to query system tables for information on the health of the AG - but this requires you to connect to each replica separately and query it. A given replica can give you the names of all replicas in the group - so you should be able to run a script on any replica, obtain list of all replicas, then perform health-check queries against each replica dynamically without hard-coding server names.

Answer (score 19):

"You use SQLCMD scripts when you have to process Windows System commands and Transact-SQL statements in the same script."

"By default, SQLCMD mode is not enabled in the Query Editor. You can enable scripting mode by clicking the SQLCMD Mode icon in the toolbar or by selecting SQLCMD Mode from the Query menu."

Reference: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: more meaningful and detailed than the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Message     Transact-SQL IntelliSense is not active for this editor because the editor is in SQLCMD mode.

I was publishing SQL Server Project from Visual Studio to Database to synchronize changes and got an error above. Publishing was failing. 
I closed all open files in VS and it resolved the issue.

I hope real life example explained why people use SQLCMD mode.