# SQL Server SQLCMD query mode in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

In Sql server management studio, when you have a new query window, you can change mode of your query window to `SQLCMD Mode` by using query menu. I use sqlcmd in windows command line but don't know what't the different of use this mode in SSMS.

[image]

Comment: I know you've been a user for a while, and I don't usually make a point of this to users like you, but I notice that a large percentage of your questions have "Thanks in advance". I really wish you wouldn't. It sets a bad example for new users. Please see "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Related post - [In SQL Server Management Studio what is SQLCMD mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9097109/465053)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a mode that allows you to create SQLCMD scripts.

MSDN - [Edit SQLCMD Scripts with Query Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187.aspx).

For a few examples look at [the SQLCMD workbench](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/the-sqlcmd-workbench/).