# How to stop code execution in sql server 2005

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

What is the similar way in SQL server 2005 to stop further line code execution like we use 
'return' or 'break' in c#.net

Comment: isn't it  `return`...?

Comment: Break is used to exit from Loop, return is to exit from sp.

Comment: This require would knowlege how to write Transact-SQL code. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182587.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx, and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181271.aspx are just three examples.

Comment: This useful article - [Flow control in T-SQL Scripts](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/merrill_aldrich/archive/2009/07/24/flow-control-in-t-sql-scripts.aspx) was mentioned in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028072/t-sql-stop-or-abort-command-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

Try using raiserror, it will terminate the connection.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try the [raiserror](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177497%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)  command. This will terminate the connection, thereby stopping the rest of the script from running.