# In SQL Server, how can I separate a large number of tsql statement into batches?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, transactions

In SQL Server, how can I separate a large number of tsql statement into batches? Should I use the **GO** statement in stored procedures or functions? Should I use the **GO** statement in explicit transaction management situation(between **BEGIN TRANSACTION** and **ROLLBACK TRANSACTION** or **COMMIT TRANSACTION**)?
Are there some best practice about this topic?
Great thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GO` is not actually a SQL keyword - it's [interpreted by SQL Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299249/what-is-the-use-of-go-in-sql-server-management-studio/2299280#2299280). So you can't use it in stored procedures.

If you're writing a script for SSMS, you can use `GO` inside a transaction, but be careful about error handling - if an error occurs, the transaction will be rolled back, but only the current batch will be aborted, and then execution will continue to the next batch. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911103/exit-and-rollback-everything-in-script-on-error).

As for best practises, personally I just use `GO` only when I have to (for example, when creating multiple stored procedures - each has to have its own batch). The fewer `GO` statements, the less work to handle errors.