# sql scripting variable default value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sqlcmd

I have a script file e.g. test.sql.  I want to call this from another script, say caller.sql, in sqlcmd mode using :r test.sql.  This works fine, but I want to use a scripting variable in test.sql.  When I call test.sql from caller.sql I can set the scripting variable and all is well.  However, I want to use a default value for the scripting value so that if the caller does not set the variable, or if I run test.sql directly (not from caller.sql) then the scripting variable defaults to a set value.

I have tried things such as

```
begin try
 select '$(grip)'
 select 'grip value was found'
end try
begin catch
 select 'grip value was missing'
end catch
```

but I just get the following message:
A fatal scripting error occurred.
Variable grip is not defined.

What do I need in test.sql so that it can cope with 'grip' either being passed by the caller or not?  I am using MS SQL 2005

Answer (score 8):

There is a LIMITED workaround (I've only tested it on SS2008R2):

### SIMPLE version - if you're willing to live without `:on error exit` / `sqlcmd.exe -b`:

```
:on error ignore -- Ensures that sqlcmd.exe will not fail when referencing an undefined scripting variable. Remove this if you want your script to work in SSMS in regular mode, too.
Declare @valueOrDefault as nvarchar(max)= N'$(value)';    
if @valueOrDefault = N'$' + N'(value)' set @valueOrDefault = N'default value'; -- Test if there is a value and, if not, assign a default; note the splitting of the reference string to avoid expansion.

-- use @valueOrDefault from now on
```

Note:

- Since T-SQL variables don't work across batches, you cannot start another batch (with GO) and so cannot switch to robust error handling with `:on error exit`.
  Therefore, *you have to do your own error handling in the remainder of the script - which is non-trivial*; see [SQL Server - stop or break execution of a SQL script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659188/sql-server-stop-or-break-execution-of-a-sql-script)
- If you remove the `:on error ignore` in order to make the script work in SSMS in regular mode, be sure that when you invoke that script with sqlcmd.exe that you do NOT specify the -b option, as that will prevent the entire script from running if the referenced scripting variable does not exist.
- By effectively turning the scripting variable into a regular T-SQL variable, you cannot use the value in places where T-SQL expects literals, such as the name of a database in a CREATE DATABASE statement.
- If the scripting variable is not defined, the following warning is printed to stderr:
  'variableName' scripting variable not defined.

### ROBUST version - much more cumbersome, but supports `:on error exit`, which is advisable:

```
-- Store the default value in the context info (session-level storage accessible across batches that holds up to 128 bytes).
declare @binDefaultValue varbinary(128)= CAST(N'default value' AS varbinary(128));
set CONTEXT_INFO @binDefaultValue;
go -- Make the set CONTEXT_INFO statement take effect.

-- If the scripting variable has a value, store ITS value in the context info instead.
:on error ignore -- Temporarily ignore errors so that accessing a non-existent scripting variable doesn't abort the entire script.
    declare @value as nvarchar(max) = N'$(value)'; -- Try to access the scripting variable; thanks to :on error ignore this will only give a warning.
    if @value <> N'$' + N'(value)' -- Test if there is a value; note the splitting of the reference string to avoid expansion.
    begin
    -- We have a scripting-variable value: Store it in the context info (replacing the default value).
        declare @binValue as varbinary(128) = cast(@value as varbinary(128));
        set CONTEXT_INFO @binValue;
    end
go -- End batch here, so we can switch back to :on error exit (requires a new batch).

:on error exit -- New batch: switch back to robust error handling.
-- End the batch here, so that SSMS in *regular* mode - which will fail on the line above - continues processing below.
-- Note that when run by sqlcmd.exe the subsequent batches will inherit :on error exit.
go

-- Retrieve the value or default value from the context info...
declare @valueOrDefault as nvarchar(max) = convert(nvarchar(max), CONTEXT_INFO(), 0);
-- ... and remove trailing null characters. ?? Is there an easier way to do this?
declare @pos as int = 0;
while @pos < LEN(@valueOrDefault)
begin
    set @pos=@pos+1
    if UNICODE(substring(@valueOrDefault, @pos, 1)) = 0  break;
end
if @pos > 0 set @valueOrDefault = left(@valueOrDefault, @pos - 1);

-- @valueOrDefault now contains the scripting-variable value or default value.
print 'Value or default value: [' + @valueOrDefault + ']';
```

Note:

- The above works both when invoked from sqlcmd.exe and in SSMS in *regular* mode - assuming you use no other SQLCMD commands in the script. Sadly, SSMS in *SQLCMD* mode  always refuses to run a script that references a non-existent scripting variable.
- The use of `SET CONTEXT_INFO` is required, because values need to be passed across batch boundaries, which can't be done with T-SQL variables. Multiple batches are needed to switch back to robust error handling.
- The code above only supports a *single* scripting variable, and, due to use of `SET CONTEXT_INFO`, its length is limited to 128 bytes = 64 Unicode characters; it's conceivable to use other workarounds, though, such as temporary tables.
- By effectively turning the scripting variable into a regular T-SQL variable, you cannot use the value in places where T-SQL expects literals, such as the name of a database in a `CREATE DATABASE` statement.
- If the scripting variable is not defined, the following warning is printed to stderr:
  'variableName' scripting variable not defined.

Comment: I think a temp table provides a more flexible and easier approach. see below

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps one of these 3 options:

- via command line option `v`
- through the `:SETVAR` command described later in this chapter
- by defining an environment variable prior to running `SQLCMD`.

**Using `v` option**

In your script: `SELECT $(foo) FROM $(bar)`
Usage: `C:>SQLCMD i c:\someScript.sql -v foo="CustomerName" bar="Customer"`

**Using `setvar`**

```
:setvar foo CustomerName
:setvar bar Customer
```

From
http://www.sqlcmd.org/sqlcmd-scripting-variables/

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, but none of these appear to address the need for a default value (within test.sql) that can be overridden by another value when called by caller.sql (I can't get it to work).  The :setvar option looks good, but the setvar in test.sql takes precedence over anything set within caller.sql

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving the variable and assign to a variable, if it falls through the SET statement then it is assigned.  The catch will handle the default values.  This works for me on SQL Server 2005.  I have noticed that this always says that it failed when I run it in SQL Management Studio even though I think it works.  When I run this via command-line using sqlcmd it works without any error messages.

```
BEGIN TRY 
    DECLARE @bogusVar VARCHAR(64);
    SET @bogusVar = '' + $(envVar);
    PRINT 'Using values passed from sqlcmd';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'Using default values for script'
    :setvar envVar 'DefaultValue'
END CATCH;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running SQLCMD from a Windows Command promt, add "2> nul" at the end of your SQLCMD statement. That will eliminate the SQLCMD complaints at the beginning of the output.

Example: sqlcmd -S DatabaseServer -E -d MyDatabase -i MyScript -v Variable1=Value1 2> nul

Comment: I've read this in many sources, but it doesn't work for me. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

What wound up being remotely practical for me is setting a system environment variable to the default and then overriding that value where desired with SQLCMD -v.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the Context is an original and interesting idea.  When I read the issues you faced parsing the VarBinary I thought perhaps a temp table would answer the need.
After working on it a bit (and then remembering your comment that SSMS ALWAYS errors :( when the scripting variable is undefined) I got this version working.  I generally don't like Name-Value solutions but performance is not really and issue here and it provides a great deal of flexibility at the cost of the boiler plate required to define and test each optional parameter.
I tested on SQL2008R2 using SSMS 17.

```
Set NoCount On;
If Object_Id('tempdb..#hold', 'U') Is Not Null Drop Table #hold;
Go
Create Table #hold(theKey NVARCHAR(128) Not Null, theValue NVARCHAR(128) Not Null);
Insert #hold(theKey, theValue) Values (N'Type', N'Full');
Select theValue From #hold Where theKey = N'Type'

:on error ignore
    Declare @theValue   NVARCHAR(128) = N'$(BType)';
    If @theValue <> N'$' + N'(BType)'   -- a value was passed in
        Update #hold Set theValue = @theValue Where theKey = N'Type';
Go
:on error exit

Select theValue From #hold Where theKey = N'Type'
Return;
-- sqlcmd -S myServer -E -i thePath\theScript.sql -v BType = "diff"
```