# How to put multiple batches into a single logical block

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql

I am writing a script that needs to do something like this:

```
IF [CONDITION]

BEGIN

--EXECUTE LOADS OF BATCHES (I.E. BLOCKS OF CODE WITH 'GO' AT THE END)

END
```

This appears not to be allowed. The `GO` statement is not allowed in a `BEGIN...END` block.

I've also tried this:

```
IF NOT [CONDITION] GOTO GetMeOutOfHere

--EXECUTE LOADS OF BATCHES (I.E. BLOCKS OF CODE WITH 'GO' AT THE END)

GetMeOutOfHere:
```

But, you guessed it, `GOTO` doesn't work across batches.

Is there any solution to this confounded conundrum?

Comment: This might be something `sqlcmd` mode can help with. Not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
IF NOT [CONDITION]

SET NOEXEC ON

--EXECUTE LOADS OF BATCHES (I.E. BLOCKS OF CODE WITH 'GO' AT THE END)

SET NOEXEC OFF
```

It does seem to work with the script I'm doing right now.

Comment: Well if that's what you want to do. See [this question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/659188/73226) for other possible methods.

Comment: It is what I want to do. The `RAISERROR` method would terminate the script entirely, whereas with `SET NOEXEC ON / OFF` I can determine a point to continue from.

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of the `GO` statements, they aren't needed as long as you aren't doing structure modifications.

If you are changing the structure, you may need to duplicate your `if` conditions.

Comment: Duplicating `IF` conditions across a large script is what I would like to avoid.