# How to display the error message when using ":on error exit" in SQLCMD mode?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, ssms, sqlcmd

I have a query with T-SQL statements in SQL Server 2012 with SQLCMD Mode turned On running interactively in SSMS. There's a `:on error exit` statement. When I run the query, the query window shows "Query completed with errors" but no error messages are displayed.

How do I get the error message to display?

Comment: USE RaiseError instead "raiserror('fatal error', 20, -1)"

Comment: read this? it might help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2590364/17447

Comment: @knkarthick24 That works if I want to raiserror because I know where it happens. Plus I can't change the code

Comment: @naveen It doesn't explain how to capture the error when it happens. I can't change the code to use raiserror.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [MSDN(RaiseError)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) to achieve what you are looking for:

Severity levels **11-19** will cause execution to  jump to the CATCH block.

```
BEGIN TRY

    RAISERROR ('Error raised in TRY block.', -- Message text.
               16, -- Severity.
               1 -- State.
               );
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    SELECT 
        @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

    -- Use RAISERROR inside the CATCH block to return error
    -- information about the original error that caused
    -- execution to jump to the CATCH block.
    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.
               @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.
               @ErrorState -- State.
               );
END CATCH;
```

Note: Using severity levels from 20 through 25 are considered fatal, will cause abrupt termination of client connection.

Answer (score 0):

It was a syntax error and not a run time error. I am not sure if SQLCMD mode doesn't show any errors in SSMS like vanilla sQL.