# Raiseerror with no message in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers, raiserror

I am writing a trigger for controlling a field. The script works as I want but my problem is in the `raiseerror`. I want the trigger to work without showing the error message to the user.

Can anyone who knows what is the equivalent of `raiseerror` without showing the error message to the user.

```
DECLARE @val varchar(9)
SELECT @val= [DC_Piece] 
from INSERTED 
where INSERTED [DC_Domaine]=0 and INSERTED.[DC_IdCol]=6

IF UPDATE([DC_Piece])
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS( select [DO_PIECE] 
    from DOCEN 
    where  @val= [DO_Piece] and [DO_Domaine]=0 and [DO_Type]=6)
        RAISERROR('STOP',11,1)
END
```

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659188/sql-server-stop-or-break-execution-of-a-sql-script

Comment: `RAISERROR` is used to generate error messages and initiate error processing. In your code, it appears that it is only used to generate error message. Can you not just remove the `RAISERROR` block. If you want the trigger to rollback the changes, you can use `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` instead.

Comment: with rollback transaction i got another message error

Comment: Just put your code to a stored procedure CREATE PROCEDURE AS ... and do RETURN instead of the RAISERROR, which will silently stop and return.