# How to terminate the sql script when the an error is raised an catched in Azure Datawarehouse

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-synapse

I'm wondering if there is a way to terminate SQL process when an error is raised an catched in Azure datawarehouse.

For example:

```
BEGIN TRY
    PRINT 'a';
    THROW 60000,'xyz',1
    PRINT 'b'
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    Print 'catched'
END CATCH

Print 'c'
Print 'd'
```

The output of the current code is: a, catched, c, d.

The desired output is a, catched. Also I'll be wrapping the try-catch block inside a while loop and printing 'c', 'd' will be outside it.

I tried "SET NOEXEC OFF", but is not working in Azure datawarehouse.

EDIT: The entire logic will be in a stored procedure

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you move `Print 'c' Print 'd'` inside the Try block? Another option is to use a Transaction block. This would be extreme, but there is this option as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/804811/8104777

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I want print 'c', print 'd' outside the try block. I understood that I can use Transactions, but the operations (Switching partitions) I'm supposed to perform can't be used inside a transaction. Please let me know if there is any other way. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add [`return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to your `catch` block to terminate execution:

```
BEGIN TRY
    PRINT 'a';
    THROW 60000,'xyz',1
    PRINT 'b'
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    Print 'catched' -- Caught.
    return
END CATCH

Print 'c'
Print 'd'
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It did worked, but I want the entire logic to be wrapped inside a stored procedure and it is not allowing as the return statement should be inside UDF. 
Is there any way the same functionality can also be implemented inside SPROC? Thank you!

Comment: @sunilkumarampolu You can use [`return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) within a stored procedure and, in that usage, it can also return an `int` as a status value. A [user-defined function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is not a stored procedure, though `return` is used in multi-statement UDFs to return a result. Is the "stored procedure" in your question a "UDF"?

Comment: @HABO the RETURN command is not supported on Azure SQL Data Warehouse or its successor Azure Synapse Analytics dedicated SQL pools.